# Add a volume indicator to my panel WITHOUT adding an indicator applet

Tags: indicator

Is there a way to ONLY add a volume indicator to my panel WITHOUT adding an indicator applet. This is not a duplicate.

The indicator applet includes a lot of other items which take up space on the panel.

Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Comment: Telling us your version of Ubuntu (or at least DEsktop) could help, or are we to guess GNOME (18.04), or UNITY (16.04 & 14.04).....  Since two versions use Unity - Unity?

Comment: Short answer is no, assuming you're using GNOME, indicator or GNOME extension are the only two things with which the panel deals with.

Comment: It seems to be impossible, but you can rearrange horizontal space as you like. For example convert *Applicatios | Places | System* to one MATE Manu launcher icon by selecting *Familiar* panel layout in *MATE Tweak*. IMHO I do not have problems with horizontal space even on 1366x768 screen (see [screenshot of top panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yslvS.png)).

Comment: I wanted to get rid of the icon that open Thunderbird.